# ¿Como se puede editar un contraseña Hasheada en Laravel?

Tags: php, login, hash

sucede que necesito crear un usuario del modelo User (del modelo que viene por defecto en Laravel) de tipo Admin, el que pueda crear y editar demás instancias o cuentas User (claro, estas no seran tipo Admin).

Al tratar de editar una contraseña, veo que solo se me muestra un hash, porque  al almacenar ese dato en DB se convierte a hash.

Averigüe y no se puede invertir el hash para obtener la contraseña original, pero con encriptación si se puede, *una opción que pensé seria hacer que el Login de Laravel funcione con contraseñas encriptadas en vez de hash*, por que  el Login por defecto de Laravel no acepta el inicio de sesión si la contraseña no es hash, intente guardando User con una contraseña encriptada en vez de ser con Hash y no funciona.

En esa ultima suposición de modificar el Login, **¿donde se puede modificar para que el Login compare contraseñas encriptadas?** De no ser posible esta solución, **¿como puedo editar una contraseña ya guardada como hash?** No se como visualizarla.

Comment: Mi idea es mostrar en la vista Edit (ingresando como el Admin), un formulario que contenga los datos del Usuario seleccionado para editar, dentro de este formulario deberían estar los Input con un Value={{old($user->name)}} digamos, para ver el nombre actual para poder editarlo sabiendo cual era. Con la contraseña esto no se debe hacer? nota: el Admin debe ser el unico que puede editar los datos de las cuentas.

Comment: Ten cuidado si decides hacer algo así para un proyecto comercial ya que puede vulnerar las leyes de protección de datos de tu país. Infórmate de las leyes antes de meterte en un lío.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las contraseñas guardada como hash propone una encriptación de un solo sentido muy segura que ir contra ella restaría calidad y seguridad en tu proyecto. No tienes que mostrar la contraseña, muestra un campo con una máscara y que el usuario pueda introducir la nueva contraseña. Mostrarle a un usuario su u otras contraseñas supone que puedes tú verla, y eso no es muy bien visto en términos de seguridad y privacidad de datos. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es que a los usuarios le resetees las contraseñas por ejemplo:

Yo registraba usuarios y la contraseña lo generaba con su DNI, ellos podian cambiarlo luego y si se olvidaban lo reseteaba otra vez por defecto con su dni y volverian a cambiarlo.